# Simple htaccess redirection

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I have a standard Drupal site and need to add a redirection rule for SEO reasons

I need to redirect /salon/whatever to /salon-locator/whatever

This is what I have at the moment but I seem to get multiple redirects

```
  RewriteEngine on

  Redirect permanent /salon/ /salon-locator/

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?q=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to stick with mod_rewrite here because after mod_alias processes the `Redirect` directive, the URI continues through the path processing pipeline and mod_rewrite gets a hold of it and mangles it. If you use only mod_rewrite, you can tell the rewrite engine to stop after you've redirected using the `L` flag. So you want to replace:

```
Redirect permanent /salon/ /salon-locator/
```

with this:

```
RewriteRule ^salon/(.*)$    /salon-locator/$1 [L,R=301]
```